# How to use aws-java-sdk-s3 with own domain?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I want to change default domain for aws-java-sdk-s3. I need to send objects not on:

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket
```

but on:

```
http://my_own_domain.com/mybucket
```

How to change it?

There is an example:

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("my_access", "my_secret");


AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
                .build();
```

But it uses domain of amazone.

Comment: Why? Amazon's S3 doesn't exist on `my_own_domain.com`, and you probably shouldn't be displaying the actual end point to users.

Comment: I don't use Amazon's S3 object storage but I use their APIs for another object storage. aws-sdk-java is under Apache License Version 2.0. So, for me it is better to use their project to work with S3 API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to, you can call setEndpoint() on the AmazonS3Client object
  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#setEndpoint-java.lang.String-